# Normalisation of test dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, normalization

I have train(x_train) and test(x_test) datasets, but I'm not sure how to normalise it.

The first option is to use mean and deviation of train dataset:

```
(x_train-np.mean(x_train))/np.std(x_train)
(x_test-np.mean(x_train))/np.std(x_train)
```

The second option is to combine x_train and x_test to get overall mean and deviation:

```
x=np.vstack((x_train,x_test))
(x_train-np.mean(x))/np.std(x)
(x_test-np.mean(x))/np.std(x)
```

Can you please explain me how to choose between these two methods, is any of them is not correct?

Comment: Think how you would prefer to normalize for unseen cases - later for inference? which one make more sense? is train and test set suppose to have the same mean and std? why would they have vastly different mean, std...if so, why would you prefer to normalize with those mean and std? why not normalize... per sample?

Comment: A testing data set is used for validating your model, so it is important to keep the testing data separate from your training data set even for the purpose of pre-processing in order to prevent "data leakage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can use sklearn library to normalize more easily.
Testing data simulates a situation that new data is coming for your model. So you can not train your model with him at all.
You should find the mean and std of the training set and use them permanently to normalize both train and test. This is your first option